# Integration of Multiplied Derivative functions

Tags: python, integration, derivative

Here is my code. It is a function that evaluates the derivative of another function at some x-value. I want it to return a valid output even for fractional order derivatives(a).

```
from scipy.special import gamma
import scipy.integrate as integrate
import sympy as sp
import scipy as sc
import math

def f(z):
    return z**2

def fracdiff(f,x,a):
    if a==0:
        return f(x)
    else:
        if math.ceil(a)-a==0:
            q=sp.diff(f(z),z,a)
            h=q.subs(z,x)
            return h
        else:  
            n=math.ceil(a)   
            g1=(1/(gamma(n-a)))         
            q1=sp.diff(f(z),z,n)
            print(q1) # showing that q1 equals 2*z
            h1= lambda z:(x-z)**(n-a-1)*2*z # for z^2 the derivative is 2*z
            ans=sc.integrate.quad(h1,0,x)
            r=ans[0]*g1
            return r


ss=fracdiff(f,1,0.5)
```

My problem is that I want to integrate `h1` which is the multiplication of `(x-z)**(n-a-1)` and `q1(the derivative of f(z))`. If I let `f(z)=z^2` and manually input `2*z` for `q1` it works fine but if I try using `q1` it says "can't convert expression to float". Any ideas why?

Comment: Can you also include the import statements in your code please? I guess `sp` is SymPy, `sc` is SciPy and where did you import the `gamma()` function from?

Comment: Sorry Amit, this is my first time using stackoverflow. I hope that clarifies things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are mixing up SymPy with SciPy. SymPy does only symbolic calculations. SciPy does only numerical calculations. If you want to calculate some intermediate results in SymPy and then use if for numerical calculations you will have to use `lambdify` ([read more here](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/numeric-computation.html)) function which is like a `lambda` function for SymPy that gives numeric results. In the following code, I used `lambdify` function twice to convert your SymPy derivative calculations into lambda functions that give numeric results which SciPy expects.

```
import sympy as sp
import scipy as sc
import math
from scipy.special import gamma

def f(z):
    return z**2

def fracdiff(f,x,a):
    if a==0:
        return f(x)
    else:
        if isinstance(a,int):
            z = sp.Symbol('z')
            q = sp.diff( f(z), z, a ) 
            qf = sp.lambdify( z, q ) #Lambdify used here 1
            h = qf(x) 
            return h
        else:
            n = math.ceil(a)
            g1 = (1/(gamma(n-a)))         
            z = sp.Symbol('z')
            q1 = sp.diff( f(z), z, n )
            q1f = sp.lambdify( z, q1 ) #Lambdify used here 2
            h1 = lambda p: q1f(p)*(x-p)**(n-a-1)
            ans = sc.integrate.quad(h1,0,x)
            r = ans[0]*g1
            return r

ss=fracdiff(f,1,0.5) # returns 1.5045055561272689
```